# Vim not detecting implicit newline characters instead of visible newline characters I am trying to strip

Tags: vim

Here's an example of some text from which I'm trying to strip those newline characters, which appear explicitly in my vim, and replace them with actual newline characters that I don't see.

But when I search for a newline character using /[\n]/, what I get isn't these visible newline characters, but instead the implicit ones. So I can't do a search and replace.

How should I address this? Here is the text:

The Reason that can be reasoned\n                            is not the eternal Reason.The name that can\n                          be namedis not     the eternal Name. The Unnamable is of heaven and earth the beginning.\n                            The Namable becomes of the\n                              ten thousand things the mother.Therefore it is said:\n                            '\n\n                            He\n                                  who desireless is found\n                              The spiritual of the world will sound.\n                              But he who     by desire is bound\n                          Sees the mere shell of things around.'                        These two things are the same in sour    ce but different in name.\n                            Their sameness\n                            is called a mystery.Indeed
it is the mystery\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for `\\n`, not `[\n]`.

doing:

```
%s/\\n/\r/g
```

Should solve your problem (I have no idea why, but vim needs `\r` instead of `\n`')